# Sending ESC/P cut command to Brother VC-500w

Tags: command-line, printing, escp

for my current project, in which I'm using the Brother vc-500w as printer, I need to perform a full cut. I intend to use ESC/P commands to do it.
For the first step I tried to send data from commandline to printer, as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47655000/12818636

In the same type I have tried following:

```
data="\x1Bia\x00"
data="${data}\x1B@"
data="${data}\x1BiC\x1"
data="${data}\x0C"
echo -ne $data | hexdump -C
```

Resulting in:
*00000000  1b 69 61 00 1b 40 1b 69  43 01 0c               |.ia..@.iC..|*

`echo -ne $data | lp -d Brother_VC_500W_6615`

Resulting in: *Anfrage-ID ist Brother_VC_500W_6615–1465 (0 Datei(en))*

I want to mention, that in case I am sending strings to the printer, he prints the strings in his default/configured parameters. But when I'm sending shown cut command he is not printing anything, only the LED indicators behaves a little strange.

I will be happy about your ideas to solve that issue.